# how to remove key values in array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a array of objects which looks like this

```
var data = [
    {
        "id": "K014-s1",
        "status": true,
        "amount": 992,
        "check": true,
      
    },
    {
        "id": "K014-s2",
        "status": false,
        "amount": 10992,
        "check": true,
       
    }
]
```

I want only certain key values from the object in the array

Required Output:

```
 var data = [
        {
            "id": "K014-s1",
            "amount": 992,
        },
        {
            "id": "K014-s2",
            "amount": 10992,
        }
    ]
```

Code I tried:

```
     var filteredData = []
        var result = data.map((obj) => {
        filteredData.push(obj.id)
        })

console.log(filteredData)
```

I tried. But don't Know how to make it. Please Help me with some solutions

Comment: The `map` method expects that you `return` a new value for each item in the array. So in your case, return an object with the two properties your want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) already creates a new array, so `result` will already be the new value you are looking for.

> The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
var filteredResult = data.map((obj) => {
   //additional logic, if needed here.
   return {
      id: obj.id,
      amount: ob.amount,
   }        
})
```

Alternatively you can of course use a for loop or array.prototype.forEach to achieve the same:

```
var filteredData = []
data.forEach((obj) => {
  filteredData.push({
    id: obj.id,
    amount: ob.amount,
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of pushing object to another array,you can simply map your data like this

```
    var result = data.map((obj) => {
        return {
                id:obj.id,
                amount:obj.amount
               }
    })
```

Comment: "Instead of pushing to another" ... map does create a new array, too.

Answer (score 0):

No need to initiate a new array because the map method returns a new array what you can do is map the array then delete the property or method that you want then return the new array. Here's a simple solution that you use for your reference

```
const filteredData = data.map(newData => {
    delete newData.status
    delete newData.check
    return newData
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can loop over array using forEach method and delete key, value pairs. For example `data.forEach((obj) => { delete obj.status; delete obj.check; })` since array is a reference type you can easily mutate it and not create a duplicate of data.